# How to get the total page count of an AFP/PDF to a .txt file in XSL FO

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using Apache fop to generate AFP and PDF files.
Everything works perfectly fine and i am struggling with one thing.

I am able to get the total page count of each file using :

```
<fo:block text-align="right">
        Page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="end"/>
</fo:block>
```

It works perfect on both AFP and PDF.

But there is one other thing im trying to achieve - getting this total page count in a .txt file.
I am using result-document to create a .txt file:

```
<xsl:result-document href="{$FileName}.txt" method="text">
            <xsl:value-of select="'abc'"/>
</xsl:result-document>
```

Here, i would like to have the total page count of the file.
How do i achieve this?

Comment: With XSL-FO, there are two processing steps, the XSLT processor transforms some XML input with a custom stylesheet to standardized XSL-FO which the Apache FOP processor know to transform to PDF (or AFP). So you can create XSL-FO output with XSLT and then, in the second step, have Apache FOP process the XSL-FO and evaluate e.g. `<fo:page-number/>`. If you use `<xsl:result-document href="foo.txt" method="text">...</xsl:result-document>`, you are not generating anything Apache FOP or any other XSL-FO processor could process.

Comment: If in case i need the total page count of each file , basically for reconciliation, then how do i do it? 
I do see that the XSL-FO file does have the page count of each file. But how do i read this ?

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to extract the page count from the FOP log when written to a text file. (Not a FOP user, so can't confirm.)

Alternatively, you could run 'pdfinfo' [1][2] or a similar command-line utility on the PDF to get the page count.

[1] https://superuser.com/questions/403672/how-to-count-pages-in-multiple-pdf-files

[2] https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/poppler-utils/pdfinfo.1.en.html